# atal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (4 ... 4) ends beyond length 3 only occuring on Nexus 5X devixes

Tags: android, crashlytics, spannablestring, spannable, spannablestringbuilder

I see this crash for a while now in my crashlytics and I cannot find a way to fix it. It only occurs on Nexus 5X devices with Android 6.0.1.

Crashlog:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (4 ... 4) ends beyond length 3
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1090)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:665)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:658)
       at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
       at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
       at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:98)
       at android.widget.EditText.performAccessibilityActionInternal(EditText.java:138)
       at android.view.View.performAccessibilityAction(View.java:8889)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.performAccessibilityActionUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:668)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-wrap6(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1194)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I cannot reproduce the crash. Neither with a physical device nor with the emulator. It seems to have something to do with the TextChanged listener. It crashes when this gets executed.

Code Example:

```
        editTextCotton.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                calculateRaidLevel();
            }
        });


public void calculateRaidLevel(){

    double CROP_VALUE_COTTON = 1.5;

    double cropValue;

    int cottonValue = 0;
    if(!editTextCotton.getText().toString().isEmpty())           cottonValue = Integer.valueOf(editTextCotton.getText().toString());

    cropValue =  cottonValue * CROP_VALUE_COTTON;

}
```

Comment: also found same issue in Nexus 5x  6.0.1 , but found no solution.